# rails simple_form - hidden field - create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for, hidden-field, simple-form

How can you have a hidden field with simple form?

The following code:

```
= simple_form_for @movie do |f|
  = f.hidden :title, "some value"
  = f.button :submit
```

results in this error:

```
undefined method `hidden' for #SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x000001042b7cd0
```

Answer (score 329, accepted):

try this

```
= f.input :title, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => "some value" }
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. `= f.input :title, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value =>  "some value" }`

Comment: This is the `simple_form` way to do hidden inputs, however, if only a hidden input is needed, then just use Rails' `hidden_field` form builder since Simple Form inherits all the form builder methods.

Answer (score 291):

**Shortest Yet !!!**

```
=f.hidden_field :title, :value => "some value"
```

Shorter, DRYer and perhaps more obvious.

Of course with ruby 1.9 and the new hash format we can go 3 characters shorter with...

```
=f.hidden_field :title, value: "some value"
```

Comment: Or <%= f.hidden_field :term_id, :value => @transaction.term_id %>

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Even though the question asked about simple form, there is no reason to use it when this accomplishes the exact same thing with a shorter syntax.

Comment: when using custom name or using the `input_html` key, this did not seem to work as expected. The accepted answer worked better

Answer (score 5):

Correct way (if you are not trying to reset the value of the hidden_field input) is:

```
f.hidden_field :method, :value => value_of_the_hidden_field_as_it_comes_through_in_your_form
```

Where    `:method`    is the method that when called on the object results in the value you want

So following the example above:

```
= simple_form_for @movie do |f|
  = f.hidden :title, "some value"
  = f.button :submit
```

The code used in the example will reset the value (:title) of @movie being passed by the form. If you need to access the value (:title) of a movie, instead of resetting it, do this:

```
= simple_form_for @movie do |f|
  = f.hidden :title, :value => params[:movie][:title]
  = f.button :submit
```

**Again** only use my answer is you do not want to reset the value submitted by the user.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: For `simple_form_for`, the `hidden` method using here is going to raise an error `undefined method `hidden' for #<SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x00007ffa6cde0be8>`

Answer (score 4):

```
= f.input_field :title, as: :hidden, value: "some value"
```

Is also an option. Note, however, that it skips any wrapper defined for your form builder.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked perfectly in my case, as they were leaving a blank rectangle on my frontend. What worked for me was -

`<%= f.text_field :title, value: "some value", type: "hidden"  %>`